# Properties of $L^2$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Does the following inequality hold in $L^{2}$ space?
$$‎ \left\lVert \sum_{‎i=1}^{‎N}‎‎\int_{0}^{t} ‎‎f_{i}(t)dt\right\rVert^{2}_{L^{2}}\leq C\sum_{‎i=1}^{‎N}‎‎ \left\lVert\int_{0}^{t} ‎‎f_{i}(t)dt\right\rVert^{2}_{L^{2}}$$
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What does $p\neq 2$ have to do with the question? Why do you call it properties of the $L^p$ norm, and not $L^2$ norm?

Comment: Confusing notation.  Do you mean $F(t)=\int_0^tf_i(t)$ to be $\int_0^tf_i(x)dx$ or something else?  Is the norm the integral of $F(t)$ or of $f(t)$?

Comment: Thanks, I need this property on $L^{2}$ space

Comment: $L^2(X,\mu)$ where $X=?$ and $\mu=?$.